# Java setting array text color

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I'm basically running a IF statement that in the condition checks if the array number[i] is equal to 18 and if so the color should be read but have had no luck with using html or setColor.

```
if (number[i].equals("18"))
            {
                number[i] = 
            }
```

What would I assign number[i] to be if the integer is 18?

Trials such as :

```
number[i].setColor(Color.red);
number[i] = number[i].setColor(Color.red)
number [i] = "<html> <font color=red> 18</font></html>";
```

Have all not worked

Should also point out 18 is stored as a string.

Comment: Set the text colour of what? Are you working with a GUI?

Comment: `String` comparison in Java is done using `String#equals` not `==`

Comment: What is `number` what can it contain?

Comment: I want to set the colour of the text in the array nmber[i]. Yes I am working in GUI.

Comment: number is a String Array which contains strings that are numbers like 1,2,3,4 and so on. I had to make it a string and not int as I will be manipulating it further later on

Comment: @Bobski might I ask how you're displaying your string?

Comment: printme[i] = new JButton (number[i] );

Answer (score 0):

After reading some documentation, Here's what I'd try.

It seems like you want to make your button some sort of icon so to do that, the easiest way is to make a picture of what you want your icon to look like, and load that into an [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29) type

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/redSquare.gif")
```

after that, just pass the icon as a parameter to your [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton%28java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon%29)

```
if (number[i].equals("18"))
{
    printme[i] = new JButton(number[i], icon)
}
```